# Show that if $f'$ is strictly increasing, then every tangent line to the graph $y = f(x)$ intersects it exactly once

Tags: calculus

> Show that if $f'$ is strictly increasing, then every tangent line to the graph $y = f(x)$ intersects it exactly once.

**Attempt**

Since $f'$ is strictly increasing, we have that $f'' > 0$ and therefore the function is concave up. Thus since in any concave up function the tangents never touch more than once, we are done.

Do I need to be more rigorous with this?

Comment: Previous comment removed because I misread the question.  Anyway, you may want to be more rigorous than that.  Specifically, actually prove that if $g$ is concave up then the tangents to $g$ never touch it more than once.

Comment: Are we assuming the function is continuous?

Comment: Continuity is necessary, otherwise it doesn't make sense to talk about $f'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Do I need to be more rigorous than this"

That depends on if you've proven that fact about convex functions in the past. If you're just making an observation without justifying it, then yes you need to be more rigorous.

**Proof:** Assume that the tangent line at $(x,f(x))$ also intersects the curve at $(y,f(y))$. WLOG $x<y$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is a point $c$ such that $x<c<y$ and $$f'(c)(y-x)=f(y)-f(x)$$ This gives $$f(y)=f(x)+f'(c)(y-x)$$ However, the equation for the tangent line at $x$ is given by $$\ell(z)=f(x)+f'(x)(z-x)$$ Since $f'(c)>f'(x)$ by assumption, it is therefore impossible for $(y,f(y))$ to fall on $\ell$